Logistic regression for experimental inference?
I'm curious if logistic regression is appropriate when the task is inferring a treatment effect on proportions (ex: success rate) when covariates are present and some imbalance across treatment and control groups is present. (In other words, essentially ANCOVA for proportions.)
I know that logistic regression models a linear trend in the log odds space. And this linear relationship is passed through a sigmoid function which converts log odds to probabilities. However, the amount of curvature associated with the nonlinear transformation is greatest near 0.0 and 1.0 and most mild near 0.5.
Are there any concerns using this approach when the data is far from 50%?
To add hypothetical context, suppose that a research lab is trying to create a treatment for a snake venom where the probability of survival is 5% without treatment. Ideally, the treatment effect will increase probability of survival. (I have no background in this space nor is it a task on my desk, so we don't need to discuss the realities of snake venom treatment.)
Is there any concern that because the control probability is so close to zero (so the sigmoid function is doing a lot of "bending" on the log odds), that estimates would be unreliable?

Sounds like your question is more related to the logit link function itself. There are many other options see here but all of them will have the property you describe. In short, no, this shouldn't be a concern, but as with anything else, you need to be concerned about extrapolation. If the treatment is significant when the baseline is 5% that doesn't mean it will be significant if the baseline is 50%.

Great caveat on the generalization of findings, thanks!
